# If an app is downloaded and never opened, is it considered Active?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

What makes an app 'Active' in the Android marketplace reporting?

Is it when it is simply downloaded and on a device, or is it when it is downloaded, installed and opened?

Comment: Opened and....?

Answer (score 5):

According to [this Market support page](https://market.android.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139628), **Active** installs are installs that haven't been uninstalled.  It doesn't mention anything about the app having to be opened.